# почему работает на половину?

Tags: php

почему к значению которое выводится прибавляется 1?зеленый новичок.учусь сам

```
$day = date("H:i:s");

function get_day($day) {
    echo "$day" . "<br>";

    if ((0<$day) && ($day<=3)) {
        return "У вас ночь";
    }
    else if ((4<=$day) && ($day<=11)) {
        return "У вас утро";
    }
    else if  ((12<=$day) && ($day<=17)) {
        echo "У вас день";
    }
    else if ((18<$day) && ($day<=24)) {
        return "У вас вечер";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Выкладывайте код текстом, а не картинкой, и у вас тут куча ошибок.

Comment: я не знал в какой последовательности мне бы пришло его копепастить учусь самостоятельно изо этого нету понятия как надо правильно... изменил некоторые значения начал работать как задумывалось только    получается  такая картина ко времени прибавляется 1.я как понимаю она выводит то что функция верна

Comment: Пока вы не исправите вопрос - на него врятли кто либо ответит, **добавьте ваш код в виде текста а не картинкой**

Comment: @JinSilver, что должен делат этот кусок кода: `echo "$day" . "<br>";`?

Comment: без этого куска кода пустое место получается....вывод переменой

Comment: а теперь самое смешное перенес echo за пределы функций  1 пропала в начале сообщения

Comment: Напиши какой вывод ожидаешь, и какой вывод получается.

Comment: я уже все сделал

Comment: @JinSilver, плохая практика в функции и выводить что-то и возвращать значение
P.S. И еще совет - почитайте что-то по форматированию кода, потому как код, что вы написали в вопросе очень сложно читается

Comment: `((18<$day)&&($day<=24))` Вот тут лучше изменить условие на `((18<=$day)&&($day<=24))` иначе в 18 часов ни одно условие не сработает.

Comment: ну первоначально так и было)

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_day($hour) {
   if ((0 < $hour) && ($hour <= 3)) {
       return "У вас ночь";
   } else if ((4 <= $hour) && ($hour <= 11)) {
       return "У вас утро";
   } else if  ((12 <= $hour) && ($hour <= 17)) {
       return "У вас день";
   } else if ((18 < $hour) && ($hour <= 24)) {
       return "У вас вечер";
   } 
}

// Функции date передаём лишь H, так как нужен лишь текущий час 

$hour = date("H");

// Передаём функции текущий час

$day = get_day($hour);

// Выводим то что вернула (return) функция

echo $day;
```

Comment: все уже работает всем спасибо

Comment: @JinSilver не забывайте закрывать решенные/неактуальные вопросы

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param $hour
 * @return string
 */
function part_of_day($hour){

    switch ($hour) {
        case (0<$hour)&&($hour<=3):
            return 'У вас ночь';
            break;

        case (4<=$hour)&&($hour<=1):
            return 'У вас утро';
            break;

        case (12<=$hour)&&($hour<=17):
            return 'У вас день';
            break;

        case (18<$hour)&&($hour<=24):
            return 'У вас вечер';
            break;

        default:
            return 'Не определено';
    }
}
```

Comment: `(4<=$hour)&&($hour<=1)` У вас так утро никогда не наступит.